# KML file saved with wrong CRS how to remove the layer shift?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have the topography layer with the British National Grid CRS EPSG 27700.

Unfortunately, the KML data represents the other CRS - EPSG 4376 WGS 84.

It's sure-fire, that the data will be shifted against this Ordnance Survey topography map.

I tried to reproject this layer in QGIS by saving it as the. CSV layer picking up the WKT geometry for CRS EPSG 277000.

When uploaded back to QGIS, the coordinates are in X and Y as expected, but the data still appears to be shifted.

The same issue has been descried here:

[Converting .kml to different projection in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68399/converting-kml-to-different-projection-in-qgis)

but neither Shapefile nor CSV or other formats helps.

How can I reproject the layer effectively by successfully overlaying the KML with the initially wrong CRS to the topographical map with the correct CRS?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I tried to play with the following option:
**SAGA-> Transform Vector Layer**

where I put value 3 for X and 4 for Y trying to match the shift between WGS84 and OSGB...

[image]

but I state, that this method is quite mistaken and even if it would work, it could be viable just for small areas.

Comment: KML is intrinsically WGS84 (4326).   You need to focus on the datum transformation options when projecting it out of WGS84 and into OSGB 1936 (BNG).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference `Coordinates are expressed in decimal degrees only.`

Comment: did you set up your OSGB transform?

Comment: I have reprojected the layer to OSGB by saving it as different format